# Windows.Networking.BackgroundUploader gives HRESULT: 0x80040154(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG) error

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am trying to implement `Windows.Networking.BackgroundUploader` in a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app, which I've read is now possible. However, when I call `CreateUpload` I get

```
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
```

The `Windows.Networking` namespace is added fine and the project builds ok.

If I create a new Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app, I can see that there are two 'Windows' references in the Object Browser, but in the Silverlight version only one is added and the `Windows.Networking`  reference is missing. This looks like the cause of the error then. My question is, how do I add the 'right' reference to the Silverlight project? Or am I missing something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select option: "Internet (Client & Server)" in your projects' Package.appxmanifest file.

MORE INFORMATION:
A Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app has both WMAppManifest.xml and Package.appxmanifest files.

When you upgrade a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight project to Windows Phone 8.1 it adds the file: "Package.appxmanifest" which contains the packaging requirements for Windows Phone 8.1 specific features.

For more details see  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642081(v=vs.105).aspx